# Android Studio - how to use libraries (from eclipse projects)

Tags: android, eclipse, migration, android-studio, java

Yes. Everybody are testing Android Studio. I'm using Eclipse in my projects and I want to migrate to Android Studio. I'm having problems with my projects.

I read this page: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

Not a great how to in my opinion.

I'm using in my project libraries that are not in .jar formats but they're eclipse projects (with checked "is library" in properties).

Could you tell me how to move my projects to Android Studio? I'm having problems and tons of errors. I'm also using Google Play Services and Android Studio showed me old versions of the same API's.

How to add for example ActionBarSherlock or Android-ViewPagerIndicator?

Shoud I import just like in eclipse all of these projects. But in Android Studio I can't mark project as library or not?

Comment: +1 for the "Not a great how to in my opinion"

Comment: You did read the part where it was called an "IO Preview"....right?   as in..not ready for full-on primetime?   Give it some time, I'm sure they'll improve the migration capabilities...heck I just downloaded 0.1.1, and immediately was prompted to update to 0.1.2.   They claim to do a weekly update or so, so just give it some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me.

In the **build.gradle** file:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile project(':MyLibrary')
}
```

And, in the IntelliJ Module file, HelloWorld.iml:

```
<orderEntry type="library" name="android-support-v4" level="application" />
<orderEntry type="library" name="MyLibrary.aar" level="project" />
```

In the library project, there’s not much to do: tell Gradle and Android Studio that this is an Android library, with apply plugin: **‘android-library’** and **option name=”LIBRARY_PROJECT” value=”true”** , respectively.

Answer (score 5):

1. Open the Project Structure (cmd-; on osx or just File > Project Structure)
2. Go to facets
3. Select the module (the project you imported)
4. there will be a "library module " checkbox at the top

Comment: Thanks. I'll try tomorrow. So I need to import my libraries projects first, then my app.

Answer (score 0):

To use Google Play Services:
In the build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42'
}
```

In the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<application >
    <meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

I actually had the android:value="4242000" but AndroidStudio auto-corrected it to the above, which compiles, so I left it, since it is less fragile.