# How to import eclipse project library in android studio?

Tags: android

I followed a tutorial where some one load library project in eclipse. now i have android studio but project is white i get is in eclipse. how do i import library projects in android studio? which is previous compile in eclipse.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have tried from file> new->import module-> browser source but it give error;

> Specify location of gradle or Android eclipse project

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20310164/how-to-import-eclipse-library-project-from-github-to-android-studio-project

Comment: this tutoral show android studio 0.36  i have android studio 2.0  so mch diffrent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio - how to use libraries (from eclipse projects)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597895/android-studio-how-to-use-libraries-from-eclipse-projects)

Comment: Follow this : http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html#migrate

Comment: not work. its tell how to import project. i want to import library

Comment: @syedahmed: please do not ask for other peoples email address, or for them to do the work for you outside of Stack Overflow. Asking for help is fine. Asking people for support outside of Stack Overflow is not.